# Unity - Slider with negative and positive values

Tags: unity-game-engine, progress-bar, uislider

I'd like to make a slider that can show negative and positive values, zero value must be the middle and default value. A kind of rudder.. I'll attach a screenshot with the goal i want to achieve.

[image]

I tought about using a sliders for my purpouse but i'm unable to set it up. Neither i found some tutorials that can help me.

Which tool could I use to achieve my goal instead of the slider? Otherwise how could I set the slider to have the effect of the image? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Slider.minValue` and `Slider.maxValue`.

Refer to below.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public Slider mSlider;

private void Initialize()
{
    mSlider.minValue = -40;
    mSlider.maxValue = 40;
    mSlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnValueChanged);
}

private void OnValueChanged(float value)
{
    Debug.Log("OnValueChanged => " + value);
}
```